# How to get code coverage report for LWC unit tests with JEST?

Tags: lightning-web-components, unit-test, code-coverage, ui, lwc-jest

I was working on the unit test setup for Lightning Web Components with Jest and tried to figure out how to get a code coverage report but found nothing in the [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.testing). By running:

```
sfdx-lwc-jest --coverage
```

I was able to receive the following coverage information in the terminal:

```
 PASS  force-app/main/default/lwc/helloWorld/__tests__/helloWorld.test.js
  c-hello-world
    ✓ displays greeting (56 ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 helloWorld.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.717 s
Ran all test suites.
```

However, I did not figure out how to get this as a report file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After running the command mentioned in the question and checking the project structure again, I saw that a */coverage* folder was automatically created that contains a lcov-report. So similar to what you might be used to from other UI frameworks.

Looking at the Jest configuration, it seems to import a default configuration (also for coverage reporting). So theoretically you might also be able to overwrite them if you want to use other reports like junit.

**jest.config.js**

```
const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');

module.exports = {
  ...jestConfig,
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/.localdevserver']
};
```

Since this was not really documented anywhere yet, I thought it would be useful to share this here in [Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).